# In php domxpath i want to grab my full footer with html tags and text

Tags: php, html, xpath, domdocument

I want to grab footer with all the html tags and text in it with domxpath.
html:

```
 <div class="footer">
 <div class="footer-new">
 <div class="footer-additional">
 <div class="add-top">
    some text here
</div>...
```

i have text links and images in my footer 
i just want all the html like we get in the source code with all tags .
Thanks..

i am trying with something like this :

```
  $dom = new DOMDocument('1.0');
  $dom->loadHTML($input);
  $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
  $tags=$xpath->query('//div[contains(@class,"footer")]');

foreach ($tags as $tag) {
  $innerHTML = '';

$children = $tag->childNodes;
foreach ($children as $child) {
    $tmp_doc = new DOMDocument();
    $tmp_doc->appendChild($tmp_doc->importNode($child,true));        
    $innerHTML .= $tmp_doc->saveHTML();
  }

 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just target the parent footer, then iterate the children then use `->saveHTML()` and continually add them inside your string container:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0');
$dom->loadHTML($input);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$tags = $xpath->query('//div[contains(@class,"footer")]');

$innerHTML = '';
if($tags->length > 0) { // if found
    foreach($tags->item(0)->childNodes as $c) {
        $innerHTML .= $dom->saveHTML($c);
    }
}

echo $innerHTML;
```

[Sample Output](http://codepad.viper-7.com/Nw8aSw)